# XSLT: get a specific attribute value from XML

Tags: xslt

I would like to extract a single attribute from an XML using XSLT, for instance "item1", this is a sample xml:

```html
<tt xml:lang="en" ttp:timeBase="media">
 <head>
  <styling>
   <style xml:id="basic" tts:color="white" tts:backgroundColor="transparent" tts:fontSize="80%" tts:fontWeight="normal" tts:fontStyle="normal"/>
  </styling>
  <layout>
   <region xml:id="default" tts:backgroundColor="transparent" tts:showBackground="whenActive" tts:origin="10% 80%" tts:extent="80% 10%" tts:displayAlign="after" tts:textAlign="center"/>
  </layout>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p begin="item1" end="item2" region="default" style="basic">text1</p>
   <p begin="item3" end="item4" region="default" style="basic">text2</p>
   <p begin="item5" end="item2" region="default" style="basic">text3</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</tt>
```

..in this case the output would be:
item1

I really appreciate any help

Comment: What XSLT have you tried so far?

Comment: why would the output be "item1" if you look up "item1"? Where is the logic?

Comment: I would like to extract only the value from the first attribute  "begin" that in this casa is "item1", I didn't try any xslt yet

Comment: Clarify question. When the output should be "item1", by what attribute, element, content, or filter do you want to find it? Do you mean "first <p> in <div>" or do you mean "@begin in any <p> that contains text1", or what exactly?

Comment: ..I mean the" @begin" in the first  "<p> in <div>", in this specific xml file the value that I need to extract is "item1", I have a lot of xml and the "@begin" changes any time, it's the variable I need to extract in some way